# Jquery Password Protected Hidden Table not working on div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is just a simple div to protect content by password. I know it's not any kinds of security. But little. The question is, its only working on table tag.

Thats mean, if I change table tag and replace with div, its not working.

Example: When

```
<table id="table">
<td id="HIDDENDIV">hidden stuff</td>
</table>
```

it works.

But when;

```
<div id="table">
<div id="HIDDENDIV">hidden stuff</div>
</div>
```

Not working.

Here's my complete code.

```js
$("#password").keydown(function() {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('button').click()
});

$("#button").click(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value == '123') {
    document.getElementById('table').classList.toggle('show');
    document.getElementById('passw').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    alert('Invalid Password!');
    password.setSelectionRange(0, password.value.length);
  }
});
```

```css
#HIDDENDIV {
  display: none;
}

#table.show div>#HIDDENDIV {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="passw">
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <input id="button" type="button" value="Login" />
</div>

<section id="table">
  <div id="HIDDENDIV">hidden stuff</div>
</section>
```

Why It's not working ?

Comment: You have a CSS rule for `#table.show tr>#HIDDENDIV` that explicitly makes it shown.

Comment: You have no `<tr>` in your table.

Comment: Please put the non-working code in the snippet at the bottom, not the working code.

Comment: @MichaelM. So how this code Should be...?

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks.... I'm happy in your suggestion.

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus I don't know because the code you provided in your question works perfectly fine. Please edit your question.

Comment: @MichaelM. Now Hidden staff not showing

Comment: @AsmaBintaYounus Hidden elements are not supposed to show. Your code still does not show any clear issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS code, remove `tr` from `#table.show > #HIDDENDIV` because you changed it to `div`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
#HIDDENDIV {
    display: none;
}
#table.show > #HIDDENDIV {
    display: block;
}

</style>

<div id="passw">
    <input type="password" id="password" />
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Login" />
</div>

<div id="table">
    <div id="HIDDENDIV">hidden stuff</div>
</div>

<script>
$("#password").keydown(function () {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById("button").click();
});

$("#button").click(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("password").value == "123") {
        document.getElementById("table").classList.toggle("show");
        document.getElementById("passw").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        alert("Invalid Password!");
        password.setSelectionRange(0, password.value.length);
    }
});
</script>
```

Attribution for `@Michael M.` in comments for mentioning the solution.

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide any working code and doesn't mention where you copied the idea from. Please edit your question to include a working code sample and attribute the comment where you stole the idea from.

Comment: @MichaelM. Hello, I'm super new here so I'm not into the rules. First, isn't the code snippet above is working code? Second, I didn't copy the idea from anywhere...?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't do anything differently than the original code snippet. Your answer is also incredibly very similar to my upvoted and first comment on the question.

Comment: @MichaelM. I'm sorry, I opened the question before you post your comment, therefore new comments are hidden by default. I've added an attribution in my answer. If there's still anything with my answer, feel free to edit it. Sorry again!